# SQL : How to fetch data while in() clause does not work

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'items'.
it has columns including index column such as below.

```
title        | name   | areacode
---------------------------------
police       | user1  | 31,31,31
FireStation  | user2  | 31,1,2
Restaurant   | user22 | 1,1,0,32,32
---------------------------------
```

when i use below statement

```
    select title, name from items where IN(31)
```

i get (police,user1) and (FireStation,user2)
However when i use IN(1)
i cannot get (FireStation, user2)

i found out that IN clause is useful when multiple values such as

```
    IN(31,1)
```

are used.

But when single value such as IN(1) or IN(0), it sometimes does not fetch data correctly. I have found out CONTAINS method. however not familiar with it.

In sum, how can i fetch (FireStation, user2) if areacode contains a value '1'? or (Restaurant, user22) when areacode has a value '0'?

Comment: I would have a look at implementing a has and belongs to many table relation ship which would require you to place all area codes into one table and then use a third table to connect area_codes to items. this join table would look something like (id, area_code_id, item_id)  It might seem a bit trickier at first but it would make it alot easier to manage and query your area codes and items in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not be storing your area code data as CSV, because it is unnormalized and therefore will be hard to work with.  That being said, MySQL has a function called `FIND_IN_SET()` which can check if a given value appears in a CSV string.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT title, name
FROM items
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('0', areacode) > 0
```

If you wanted to check for both the `0` or `1` area code, you could use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('0', areacode) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET('1', areacode) > 0
```

Comment: I really appreciate your brilliant answer. however then, isn't there a way to use IN and FIND_IN_SET together? i have small knowledge in sql statements sorry

Comment: or do i just use where find_in_set OR IN() ??

Comment: You can add additional `FIND_IN_SET()` checks.  I will update my answer.